# Is it possible to prevent a website from redefining key combinations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm using a website-based software suite that has keyboard shortcuts. One such shortcut is Ctrl+A, which, instead of the standard "select all", has been redefined to "add another" item to the database. This frustrates me to no end, because my muscle memory is having a hard time unlearning that it means "select all." I'm looking for a way to return the default functionality.

I know that Firefox allows users to prevent websites from overriding keyboard shortcuts, but I'm required to use Chrome or Edge for this project, so that's a non-starter. My first instinct was to try a simple userscript like this (I've redacted identifying information):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         -
// @namespace    -
// @version      0.1
// @description  Return Ctrl+A functionality
// @author       -
// @match        -
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key == "a" && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

But the website's own event listeners are being attached first and so they're also being handled first by the browser. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { ... }, true);`?

Comment: In addition to the above also use `window` not `document`.

Comment: Adding `true` to the event listener did the trick, thanks double-beep. I didn't need to change the target from `window` to `document` and my understanding is that keyboard events are designed to fire on `Document` and `Element` objects? From the [Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).